# Securized the login system in symfony 3

Tags: php, php-5.3, symfony, symfony-security

I have a problem with my system login in symfony 3. So my `security.yml` is:

```
security:
role_hierarchy:
  ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
  ROLE_FMTI:        ROLE_FMTI
  ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
firewalls:
  dev:
      pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
  secured_area:
      pattern:    ^/admin
      anonymous: ~
      form_login:
          always_use_default_target_path: true
          default_target_path: /admin/homepage
          login_path:  /admin/login
          check_path:  /admin/login_check
      logout:
          path:   /admin/logout
          invalidate_session: true
          target: /admin/login
  access_control:
  - { path: ^/admin/homepage, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

 providers:
  in_memory:
      memory:
          users:
              admin: { password: admin, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }

 encoders:
  Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

The routing :

```
app_admin_homepage:
  path:     /homepage
  defaults: { _controller: AppAdminBundle:Login:index }
login:
  path:   /login
  defaults:  { _controller: AppAdminBundle:Login:login }
login_check:
  path:   /login_check
logout:
  path: /logout
```

And the method login from LoginController :

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('AppAdminBundle:Member:login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

The problem is that if, I'm login in the application with credentials : admin/admin. After that I do the logout.

1. If I tried to access `test.dev/admin/homepage` ----> I'm redirecting vers login page witch is `test.dev/admin/login`, so it's good, I'm login as `admin`.
2. If I tried to access `test.dev/admin/news/all` -----> I can access this page without do the login, and I'm login as `anonymous`

So I want to redirect to login page for all routes `/admin/*` if user is not authentificated. Thx and sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the access Control you need to add this :

```
access_control:
  - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Which means that for anything beyond the /admin/ route the ROLE_ADMIN is required.

-- update

If you need to access to /admin/login/ you need to add to every admin route except the /login, a path pattern like /admin/api/, so in your access control you gonna have this :

```
access_control:
      - { path: ^/admin/api/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```